# "sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: main.person.id" -sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

I generate an SQL statement using python. When I print it out it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item
LEFT JOIN person
ON item.owner_id = person.id
LEFT JOIN person
ON item.assignee_id = person.id
```

When I try to run my code, I get the following error (from Flask/Jinja):

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: main.person.id
```

An item can have an owner and an assignee. They can be different people.
The data for the owners and the assignees come both from the table person.

In the end I want a statement that gives me an item including the owner and the assignee of it.

Just for your info: The original statement is a bit longer, I let out some stuff  i saw as unnecessary for the question.

Comment: Why two joins? Can you do 1 join with an and clause in the on and can you specify the columns instead of * - doing that does that work?

Comment: Are you sure one join is enough? It looks like you need the other join as well. Just use different table aliases, something like `... LEFT JOIN person AS p1 ON item.owner_id = p1.id ...`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do self-joins, you have to alias the tables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM item
LEFT JOIN person AS p1
ON item.owner_id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN person AS p2
ON item.assignee_id = p2.id
```

Check the ON clauses. I assumed that this is what you meant, but I might be wrong.

Comment: That is the solution that jarhl already proposed. It works when I use it in the DB Browser, so the SQL is fine. Still have a problem with getting the data to the GUI, but that is another issue ...